# Ansible Module to list iam users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-iam

Is there any modules in Ansible to list out cloud (like AWS) IAM users, as far as i see there are modules to create, update, delete group, users and roles. But not to get list of users. In that case we have to use command line option or shell option alone?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that is currently in a PR state, that you can use if you are using the latest ansible [iam_user_facts.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/2314)

Comment: in PR for a mere ~2.5mo (so far).

Comment: The question was if a module existed. There is indeed a module and it is in a PR state. I'm not sure if the PR being 2.5 months old is bad or good or why it matters. That PR may never get merged in or it may, but it is does address the posters question.

Comment: Sure, but giving a hint to the project's cadence is relevant. Some projects are very fast from PR to code shipping. This one isn't. (one great workaround is to add it to your local `library/`)

Comment: Thanks guys,but i need to know how can we change password periodically after some mentioned days using  AWS CLI commands,i know to change in GUI of AWS.But how can we use commands?

Comment: Also what Aws command we use for getting last updated password,there is command for last usedpasword,but for last changed password is there any ?